# Get Data Type for OID with PySNMP

Tags: python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

I need to find the object name and data type for a given OID. I can get the name, but can't find the functionality in PySNMP to also return the data type (integer, octet string, counter...).

What I have so far (example):

```
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler

mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/usr/share/snmp/mibs'])
mibBuilder.loadModules('IF-MIB', ...)
mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)

oid, label, suffix = mibView.getNodeName((1,3,6,1,2,1,31,1,1,1,6))
print(label)
```

This returns the name for the oid (ifHCInOctets) but I also need it to return the data type, which in this case would be Counter.

Is there a function in PySNMP to find the data type?

Comment: Hmm, oddly not obvious from [the reference](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#mib-services)

Comment: Absolutely not. I was sure this functionality was included somewhere, but couldn't find it documented anywhere. Solved now for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pysnmp model, there is the `MibBuilder` class which loads MIB objects into memory and address them by their MIB name and MIB object name.

On top of `MibBuilder` there is the `MibViewController` class which maintains a couple of indices to address the same MIB objects (as held by `MibBuilder`) by their other attributes such as OID.

Therefore:

```
from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, compiler

# Load MIB objects, index them by MIB::name
mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()

# If Pythonized MIB is not present, call pysmi parser to fetch
# and compile requested MIB into Python
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/usr/share/snmp/mibs'])

# Load or compile&load this MIB
mibBuilder.loadModules('IF-MIB')

# Index MIB objects (as maintained by `mibBulder`) by OID
mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)

# Look up MIB name and MIB object name by OID
modName, symName, suffix = mibView.getNodeLocation((1,3,6,1,2,1,31,1,1,1,6))

# Fetch MIB object
mibNode, = mibBuilder.importSymbols(modName, symName)

# This might be an ASN.1 schema object representing one of SNMP types
print(mibNode.syntax.__class__)
```

The documentation is lacking indeed.... Though this is improving in the upcoming version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I've tried to make sense of the documentation, but couldn't find anything helpful. This solves my problem perfectly.